# Efficient way to approximate values based on position in range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure there's a better way to describe what I'm trying to do, but here's an example.
Say I have a dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 5, 10, 22, 36, 57], 'col2': [100, 450, 1200, 2050, 3300, 6000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   col1  col2
0     1   100
1     5   450
2    10  1200
3    22  2050
```

and a second dataframe (or series I suppose):

```
d2 = {'col2': [100, 200, 450, 560, 900, 1200, 1450, 1800, 2050, 2600, 3300, 5000, 6000]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2
    col2
0    100
1    200
2    450
3    560
4    900
5   1200
6   1450
7   1800
8   2050
9   2600
10  3300
11  5000
12  6000
```

I need some efficient way to assign a value to a second column in df2 in the following way:

1. if the value in df2['col2'] matches a value in df['col2'], assign the value of df['col1'] in the same row.
2. if there isn't a matching value, find the range it fits in and approximate the value based on that. e.g for df2.loc[1,'col2'], the col2 value is 200, and it belongs between 100 and 450 in the first dataframe, so the new value would be (5-1)/(450-100) *200 = 2.2857

Edit: the correct example should be (5 - 1) / (450 - 100) * (200 - 100) +1 = 2.1429

Comment: If you want to use linear interpolation, then your example would translate into: interpolate the point `(200, ?)` between the points `(100, 1)` and `(450, 5)`. The answer would have been `(5 - 1) / (450 - 100) * (200 - 100) = 2.1429`. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's correct with the addition of the low value in the second coordinate? So in this case you actually meant (5 - 1) / (450 - 100) * (200 - 100) +1 = 2.1429 , right?

Comment: That’s my suggestion but does it align with your expectation of what the interpolated value needs to be?

Comment: Yes, it does. The formula in the original post is wrong, then. I'll edit it.

In this case, would you have a suggestion of an efficient way to do this with pandas or python in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that have you confirmed your requirement, we can make a solution. We can use a loop to find segments that are bounded by non-NaN values and linear-interpolate the points in-between.

This algorithm only works when `col1` is anchored by non-NaN values on both ends, hence the `assert` statement.

```py
col1, col2 = df2.merge(df, how='left', on='col2')[['col1', 'col2']].to_numpy().T
assert ~np.isnan(col1[[0, -1]]).any(), 'First and last elements of col1 must not be NaN'

n = len(col1)
i = 0
while i < n:
    j = i + 1
    while j < n and np.isnan(col1[j]):
        j += 1
    if j - i > 1:
        # The linear equation
        f = np.polyfit(col2[[i,j]], col1[[i,j]], deg=1)
        
        # Apply the equation on all points between i and j
        col1[i:j+1] = np.polyval(f, col2[i:j+1])
    i = j
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered training a regression model on your first dataframe, then predicting the values on your 2nd?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html